# is there any way to get common values between two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a possibility of doing inner join between two arrays in php? for example

if i have two arrays array1,array2

Input :

```
array1[0]['id']=1 , array1[1]['id']=2 , array1[2]['id']=3

array2[0]['id']=3 , array2[1]['id']=4 , array2[2]['id']=5
```

Output :

```
array2[0]['id']=3;
```

is it possible to retrieve common values with any inbuilt functions?

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php ? What is expected result of this "inner join"? Your arrays are not valid.

Comment: i had edited the file with required output..

Comment: Fine.. Then array_instersect would nicely for you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [**`array_intersect()`**](https://www.php.net/array_intersect) function might be the one you are looking for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't exactly understand what you need.

If i'm guessing right, i think u need intersection of two arrays..

[array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) can do this ...

If this is not what u want, then please update your question with exact input and expected output..