# PHP array compare issue

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any way to get common values between two arrays in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513121/is-there-any-way-to-get-common-values-between-two-arrays-in-php)

I am trying to compare 2 `arrays` and keep the elements based on the second `array`.

I have

```
array 1

array('3' => 'test1', '4' => 'test2', '1' =>'test3')



array 2

array('2' =>'test2', '3' =>'test3')
```

I want to compare `array 1` and `array 2` and keep the test 2 and test 3 in `array 1` in my case.

So the end result will be

```
array('4' => 'test2', '1' =>'test3')
```

I have tried `array_diff` but it doesn't come out the results I wanted. I also google for a while but coudln't find anything useful either.

Are there anyways to get what I need? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming you just want the common elements in both arrays? http://php.net/array_intersect

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried, and then explain what didn't work.

Comment: Your example is ambiguous: it's not clear from it alone whether you want the intersection of the values (as AndreKR's answer assumes) or the difference of the keys (as I did). Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the function you *really* want is [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key):

```
$diff = array_diff_key($array1, $array2);
```

([demo on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/aNQ1R7wQ))